# Import data through spring data to neo4j graphDB

Tags: spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j, graphdb

I am building an application with the spring boot framework. I can easily use spring data to query data from db, but is there anyway I can send the `merge` query like below, instead of first creating thousands of object and save them like this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30494097/neo4j-spring-data-neo4j-4-0-0-importing-large-datasets).

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM
'file:///existed_file.csv' as line
WITH line
MERGE (n:Item {itemId: line.id)})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `@Query` to on a repository, or use the OGM [`session.query`](https://neo4j.com/docs/ogm-manual/current/reference/#reference:session:loading-entities:query-strategy) to directly execute your Cypher statement.

However, SDN is not suited for data import in general (see [When not to use SDN](https://graphaware.com/spring-data-neo4j/)).

Comment: `@Query` is allowed customized queries. But in the repository, I need to `extends Neo4jRepository`, where I need to specify a node class in `<>` before I use `@Query` in my understanding. I don't see any example that directly uses `@query` without extending neo4jrepository. But @query for updating data doesn't return anything right

Comment: Yes, in this case it does not matter, you can put it into the appropriate repository

Comment: Suppose I have put it into a certain repository, what is the proper way to write the `@query`? Let's take the above query as an example. Since the merge query returns nothing, what class shall I declare after the `@Query`? Can I do `@Query(MERGE QUERY) String Update(){return "Succeed!"};`

Comment: Just return void

Comment: It seems `@Query` doesn't allow `USING PERIODIC COMMIT`. So I switch to `apoc.periodic.iterate` and `apoc.load.csv`, but I keep getting the error `Error executing query: Scalar response queries must only return one column. Make sure your cypher query only returns one item.`